# Deleting sheet in Excel 365

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I have below VBA code:

```vb
Sub abc()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks("Book1.xlsx")
wb.Sheets("sheet1").Activate
On Error Resume Next
wb.Sheets("Sheet2").Delete
wb.Sheets("Sheet3").Delete
End Sub
```

I have 1 blank Excel file (Book1.xlsx) with 2 sheets (sheet1 and sheet2).

In Excel 2013 it works.

The same code in Excel 365 is throwing error message

> Run time error 9: subscript out of range

Comment: Which line is actually causing the error?

Comment: Dou you have a `Sheet3` in the workbook?

Comment: I have used "On Error Resume Next" so even though "sheet3" is not present vba code should skip the line and should not give error while running in excel 365.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub abc()

    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks("Frou Frou.xlsx") '<- Check if the workbook has the correct name.

    With wb

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False '<- Remove alerts asking for confirmation of deleting the sheet

            .Sheets("Sheet2").Delete '<- Check if the both sheets appear in the workbook.
            .Sheets("Sheet3").Delete

        Application.DisplayAlerts = True '<- Remove alerts

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub deleteSelectedSheets()
    Dim wb         As Workbook
    Dim sht        As Worksheet

    Set wb = Workbooks("Your.xlsx")

    For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
        Select Case sht.name
            Case Is = "Sheet1"  ' You can add as many case as you want
                sht.Delete
            Case Is = "Sheet2"
                sht.Delete
            Case Else
                ' Do nothing
        End Select
    Next sht
End Sub
```